# How to get correct Set-Cookie headers for NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsurlconnection, setcookie

I want to use the following code to login to a website which returns its cookie information in the following manner:

```
Set-Cookie: 19231234
Set-Cookie: u2am1342340
Set-Cookie: owwjera
```

I'm using the following code to log in to the site, but the print statement at the end doesn't output anything about "set-cookie".
On Snow leopard, the library seems to automatically pick up the cookie for this site and later connections sent out is set with correct "cookie" headers. But on leopard, it doesn't work that way, so is that a trigger for this "remember the cookie for certain root url" behavior?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uurl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"keep-live" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];
[request setValue:@"300" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Keep-Alive"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:10.0];

NSData *urlData;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

NSLog(@"response dictionary %@",[response allHeaderFields]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
```

This line causes the system to handle cookies for you.

Comment: Since I don't have a leopard environment, a leopard user of my app tells me it doesn't work even though I have included this [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];.

Comment: That part, I can't readily explain.

With HTTPShouldHandleCookies set to YES on at least 10.5 and 10.6 and I think all the way back to 10.2 or so, the cookies set and sent should be to/from the same cookie store used by Safari.

Comment: I put [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES] at top of set statements and it works, and wonder why. :)
Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Isaac > "from the same cookie store used by Safari" : Note that a sandboxed Mac App Store app will no longer get these cookies.